# Updating table column with value from another column in same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to make duplicate of a column, but also I don't want to delete the old one. What would be the right way to copy value from one column into another? I have tried something like this, but it's not working:

```
Users::update([
    'from_status' => 'status'
]);
```

I have to mention that, using `MySQL Workbench` I have already added new column into table (it's column `from_status`).
Also is it possible to update multiple columns at once this way? Column `status` is not the only one I am trying to duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this task. And one of the simplest and the most straight way to do this is like following:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user){
   $user->from_status = $user->status;
   $user->save();
}
```

> Also is it possible to update multiple columns at once this way?

Yes. The same way by adding one more line for each column:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user){
   $user->from_status = $user->status;
   $user->column2 = $user->some_column;
   $user->save();
}
```